# How to convert a string with AM/PM to a datetime object in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, strptime

Here's an example string for the date/time i'm trying to convert:

```
10/18/2017 5:41:28 AM
```

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
x = datetime.datetime.strptime(y, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p")
```

It basically works but it ignores the %p part (the AM/PM) and carries over the hour identical to the initial string.

Is there any way to convert the AM/PM information over so my datetime object is correct in the end? I thought the %p should do this via `strptime()`